# Scalding for Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, scalding

I wrote my build.sbt like this:

```
name := """scala-hbase"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"
//scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

/* HBase dependencies */
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Apache Repo"   at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "Thrift-Repo"   at "http://people.apache.org/~rawson/repo",
  "ClouderaRepo"  at "https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases",
  "ClouderaRcs"   at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cdh-releases-rcs",
  "Twitter Maven" at "http://maven.twttr.com",
  "MVN Repo" at "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact",
  "releases"      at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases"
)

// Hbase 0.94 / Hadoop 2.5.2
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    //"org.apache.zookeeper" % "zookeeper" % "3.4.6",
    //"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.4.5" % "test",
    "org.apache.hadoop"     % "hadoop-core"         % "1.2.1",
    "org.apache.hbase"      % "hbase"               % "0.94.16",
    "com.twitter"    %% "scalding-args"  % "0.10.0",
    "com.twitter"    %% "scalding-core"  % "0.10.0",
    "com.twitter"    %% "scalding-date"  % "0.10.0"
)
// Uncomment to use Akka
//libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.3.3"
```

```
But I got some unresolved dependencies
    [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    [warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
    [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    [warn]  :: com.twitter#scalding-args_2.11;0.10.0: not found
    [warn]  :: com.twitter#scalding-core_2.11;0.10.0: not found
    [warn]  :: com.twitter#scalding-date_2.11;0.10.0: not found
    [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

What version of scalding should i use for scala 2.11 ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cascading-user/jkARDNH770E)

```
We don't compile for 2.11.0 since its super hard/impossible to have code compatible from 2.9 -> 2.11.
We (at twitter) are still on 2.9.x for the moment so for now we can only support up to the 2.10.x scala's. Hopefully this will change over the next few months.
```

Also the current scalding version(0.12) is compatible only with scala 2.10([maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter/scalding-core_2.10))

As @Travis mentioned in the comment, Scalding for Scala version 2.11 is available in the scalding's develop branch([github](https://github.com/twitter/scalding))

Comment: can i just uncomment this line : //scalaVersion := "2.10.4" and comment line before ?

Comment: Please note that that information is a little out of date—Twitter moved to Scala 2.10 several months ago, and 2.11 support is now available in Scalding's `develop` branch.

Answer (score 3):

Scalding 0.13 is now released and it does support Scala 2.11.
https://github.com/twitter/scalding/releases